# Multiple entities in FormView

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, formview

Using ASP.net entity framework. I have an assosiation between two entities in my database (one->many). Now I only returning the first entity data to the webpage using this code. How can I return both the entity and it's associatives?

Server side

```
public IQueryable<Exercise> GetExercise([QueryString("exerciseID")]int? exerciseID)
    {

        IQueryable<Exercise> query = null;

        var context = new TrainingModelContainer();
        if (exerciseID.HasValue && exerciseID > 0)
        { 
        query = from e in context.ExerciseSet where e.Id == exerciseID select e;  
        }

        return query;
    }
```

Web

```
<asp:FormView ID="exerciseView" runat="server" ItemType="WebApplication1.Exercise" SelectMethod="GetExercise" RenderOuterTable="false">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div>
                <p><%#:Item.Description %></p>
                <p><%#:Item.Date%></p>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
```

Comment: Is your question about returning data via EF, or about displaying related data via ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you probably need the [`Include`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx) method:

```
 context.ExerciseSet.Include("Associatives") where e.Id ....
```

The longer answer (for you) is that it is better to use a view model which enables you to define exactly what you send to the client. In most cases such a model can simply be populated by a projection from your linq query:

```
 ... select new ExerciseSetModel { Property1 = e.Property1, Property2 = ... }
```